# Symfony does not fire security.login.failure event. Does not call listener function

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

Just as the title says.
If i use

App\EventListener\AuthListener:

```
tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.authentication.success', method: 'onLoginFailure' }
```

then the method gets called on successful login.

If I change the event to 'security.login.failure' (like it says in the documentation)

App\EventListener\AuthListener:

```
tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.login.failure', method: 'onLoginFailure' }
```

,
the event is never fired although the documentation says it should be fired every time a wrong password is entered.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#authentication-events

Symfony version 6.0, "symfony/security-bundle": "6.0.*",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the tag 'security.login.failure' to full class name: 'Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LoginFailureEvent' fixed the problem.

Comment: It's odd that security.login.success appeared to work.  Maybe a typo?  Did `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` show your listener?  I guess it does not really matter.  By the way, using an event subscriber can save a few lines of configuration.

Comment: No typos, security.authentication.success worked, yes. console debug showed the listener, yes, but it doesn't really check for the existence of the event. I can put anything in the event name and the debug:event-dispatcher will list it. Thanks for the idea, but I am upgrading some legacy software so I probably won't change the structure.